# How to apply a condition to Pandas dataframe rows, but only apply the condition to rows of the same day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that's indexed by datetime and has one column of integers and another column that I want to put in a string if a condition of the integers is met. I need the condition to assess the integer in row X against the integer in row X-1, but only if both rows are on the same day.

I am currently using the condition:

```
df.loc[(df['IntCol'] > df['IntCol'].shift(periods=1)), 'StringCol'] = 'Success'
```

This successfully applies my condition, however if the shifted row is on a different day then the condition will still use it and I want it to ignore any rows that are on a different day. I've tried various iterations of `groupby(df.index.date)` but can't seem to figure out if that will work or not.

Comment: Please post a sample dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but gets you the answer:

```
df['out'] = np.where(df['int_col'] > df.groupby(df.index)['int_col'].shift(1), 'Success', 'Failure')
```

Comment: I think you need to use df.index.date

Comment: definitely more concise and using np is faster than apply() method. Needs .date as EBDS mentions

Comment: This does work for me after adding .date. I have tried the np.where function before but I was attempting to use df.groupby on both sides of the condition. Why is it that df.groupby only goes on the side of the condition with the shift(1)? I would have thought the code would then by working with two different data sets and you would have to use groupby on the entire condition.

Comment: This article provides a detailed explanation in #6:
https://towardsdatascience.com/8-popular-sql-window-functions-replicated-in-python-e17e6b34d5d7

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. You were probably closer to the answer than you thought...

There is two dataframes use to show that the logic you have works whether or not data is random or integers are sorted range.

You will need to import random to see the data

```
dates = list(pd.date_range(start='2021/1/1', periods=16, freq='4H'))

def compare(x):
    x.loc[(x['IntCol'] > x['IntCol'].shift(periods=1)), 'StringCol'] = 'Success'
    return x

#### Will show success in all rows except where dates change because it's a range in numerical order
df = pd.DataFrame({'IntCol': range(10,26)}, index=dates)
df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(compare)

2021-01-01 00:00:00      10       NaN
2021-01-01 04:00:00      11   Success
2021-01-01 08:00:00      12   Success
2021-01-01 12:00:00      13   Success
2021-01-01 16:00:00      14   Success
2021-01-01 20:00:00      15   Success
2021-01-02 00:00:00      16       NaN
2021-01-02 04:00:00      17   Success
2021-01-02 08:00:00      18   Success
2021-01-02 12:00:00      19   Success
2021-01-02 16:00:00      20   Success
2021-01-02 20:00:00      21   Success
2021-01-03 00:00:00      22       NaN
2021-01-03 04:00:00      23   Success
2021-01-03 08:00:00      24   Success
2021-01-03 12:00:00      25   Success

### random numbers to show that it works here too
df = pd.DataFrame({'IntCol':  [random.randint(3, 500) for x in range(0,16)]}, index=dates)
df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(compare)

                     IntCol StringCol
2021-01-01 00:00:00     386       NaN
2021-01-01 04:00:00     276       NaN
2021-01-01 08:00:00     143       NaN
2021-01-01 12:00:00     144   Success
2021-01-01 16:00:00      10       NaN
2021-01-01 20:00:00     343   Success
2021-01-02 00:00:00     424       NaN
2021-01-02 04:00:00     362       NaN
2021-01-02 08:00:00     269       NaN
2021-01-02 12:00:00      35       NaN
2021-01-02 16:00:00     278   Success
2021-01-02 20:00:00     268       NaN
2021-01-03 00:00:00      58       NaN
2021-01-03 04:00:00     169   Success
2021-01-03 08:00:00      85       NaN
2021-01-03 12:00:00     491   Success
```

Comment: You're right, I was quite close to that at several points but just didn't quite have the syntax correct. The strange thing now is that the condition is never true when used with a groupby. I basically have the exact scenario as your random numbers example but I do not get the same output, and in fact if I use the same example dataframes as you then I still get no true conditions. How can I copy the exact code and get a different result?

Comment: Unsure why you'd get different results, but you can use Poorval Dhotre's answer as it works too and it's faster solution.